# How to remove index.php from URL path except if the path is /index.php/

Tags: regex, .htaccess

I need to remove index.php from inner pages so that the URL path like `/index.php/path` would be just `/path`. But at that if the path is `/index.php/` then not to remove index.php and leave everything as is. I try the following lines in my `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^.*/index.php/$ [NC]
RewriteRule /index.php/(.+)$ /$1
```

But they remove index.php always including when the path is `/index.php/`

Answer (score 1):

You can use these 2 rules in your site root .htaccess:

```sh
RewriteEngine On

# external redirect to remove /index.php
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+index\.php/(\S+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [R=301,L,NE]

# If the request is not for a valid directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# If the request is not for a valid file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
# rewrite to /index.php/<uri>
RewriteRule .+ index.php/$0 [L]
```